# Post request to AWS Lambda URL

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have an AWS Lambda function that is meant to receive a json, pass it to a machine learning model and return a prediction.

The tests are working well, so now I want to configure a Function URL. My goal is to be able to post a request to the function's URL from my local computer and have it respond with a prediction.

For the purpose of this question, suppose the function looks as follows:

```py
# Silly function
def lambda_handler(event, context):

    # Extract values from request
    x = list(event.values())

    # Return
    return {
        'status': '200',
        'inputs': x
    }
```

Hence, the test event `{"feature1": 12, "feature2": 34}` responds with the expected result:

```
{
  "status": "200",
  "inputs": [
    12,
    34
  ]
}
```

I just configured a URL through:

> Configuration > Create Function URL > Auth type = None > Save.

How can I post requests to this URL to get the same response as the test event?

In other words, can I send the same test event via Insomnia (or Postman) to the URL and get the same response as the test event?

Comment: Sort of https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/urls-invocation.html . The payload you send can be identical to the test event. What the lambda receives is a bit more complicated but your input is in there somewhere.

Comment: Also, you can just use: `x = list(d.values())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading [the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/urls-invocation.html), I realized that the information I wanted to extract was contained in the `"body"` element nested inside the `event` received by the function.

I had to adapt my function to extract the `"body"` from `event`.

```py
# Function to load jsons passed as strings
from json import loads

# Silly function
def lambda_handler(event, context):

    # Extract body from event
    body = event['body']

    # Extract values from body
    x = list(body.values())

    # Return
    return {
        'status': '200',
        'inputs': x
    }
```

I had to do this because `event` looks like this in the background.

```
{
   "headers":{<headers here>},
   "isBase64Encoded":false,
   "rawPath":"\/",
   "routeKey":"$default",
   "requestContext":{<context here>},
   "body":"{\"feature1\": 12,\n\t\"feature2\": 34}",
   "version":"2.0",
   "rawQueryString":""
}
```

My mistake came from thinking that `{"feature1": 12, "feature2": 34}` was contained directly inside `event`, when in reality, it was nested inside `"body"`.